# How do I scrape and combine multiple application/ld+json tags?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm writing a script to pull metadata out of submitted (external) URLs. I found a very helpful post that got me 90% of the way there, however it assumes there's only going to be one relevant script tag, and I need to parse pages that have multiple script tags.

How can I modify the below statement so that it combines all matching json script tags into one chunk of json?

```
$xp = new domxpath($d);
$jsonScripts = $xp->query( '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]' );
$json = trim( $jsonScripts->item(0)->nodeValue );

// decode the JSON string we find into a associative array
$data = json_decode( $json, true );
```

Comment: You can just use a `foreach` over `$jsonScripts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% without testing the code, but `$jsonScripts` will contain multiple items if there is more than one, and the total number of these can be obtained using the `length` property.

To go through them all, use a simple `for` loop to obtain each one:

```
...
$jsonScripts = $xp->query( '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]' );
$json = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $jsonScripts->length; $i++) {
    $json .= trim($jsonScripts->item($i)->nodeValue );
}
...
```

This will simply concatenate the contents of each script node onto the `$json` variable.  I'm not certain whether you want to separate them by a delimiter or anything else.

Where your code was previously using:

```
$json = trim( $jsonScripts->item(0)->nodeValue );
```

This was obtaining only the *first* element.  The code I suggested uses:

```
$json .= trim($jsonScripts->item($i)->nodeValue);
```

This concatenates the `$i`th element and should therefore output all of them starting with the `0`th.